# sqlite3 show number of rows selected at the end of query result

Tags: sqlite

In Oracle SQLPlus when there is a select, at the end it shows how many rows selected. Is there a mode to turn on for sqlite3 to show the same information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sqlite3` command-line shell has no such function.